# ToggleButton image does not maintain aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

The two toggle buttons don't maintain aspect ratio. How can I make it a square? It shouldn't fill the width but just wrap it's content.

[image]

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:textOn=""
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/feedback_btn_selector"
                    />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/feedback_btn_selector" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

**feedback_btn_selector**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_average" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_average"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_average"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_average_selected"/>
</selector>
```

drawable-xhdpi:

[image]

Comment: You have set toggle button width as wrap content. It should fill it's width according to it's content.

Comment: @Md.Didarulislam no this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can make small size of image as you want or make `ToggleButton` with fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textOff=""
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:textOn=""
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/feedback_btn_selector"
            />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/feedback_btn_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With this solution, the images are square, but not equally distributed in the middle of the screen. With adding                     android:gravity="center_horizontal" to LinearLayout, the solution is correct. Thanks!

Comment: I answered the question of the ratio. Good for you then ! you may check this answer as a solution then

Answer (score -1):

Correct answer:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textOff=""
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:textOn=""
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/feedback_btn_selector"
            />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/feedback_btn_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>
```